# Track the total amount of API requests in Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, ruby-grape, grape-api

I have a set of grape APIs which run on Rack.

Is there any way to get total amount of API requests after the server start?

Is there any other way how API request count can be tracked?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [statsd-ruby](https://github.com/github/statsd-ruby) library together with [statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd).

You would just need to call `statsd.increment` with the counter name in the `before_action` on your `ApplicationController`.

There are many backends for statsd, which aggregate the data. The easiest way would be to use some service, like [datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/).